# Multiple submissions in a single form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I am creating a form which collects user's residential data. First the user needs to select country, then state, then city(these are dependent dropdowns). Then user has to fill his personal details and then submit the form.

Here user has to select country, then hit submit button, follow the same for state. And finally hit submit button to submit the complete form.

UI looks something like this: 
[image: Form]
Now, while clicking the submit button at the end, I have to validate all the fields. I have to only ensure that all the fields aren't empty.

Since I have to submit the country and state data, I tried nesting the forms, which didn't work.

What can be done?

Comment: P.S.: The two fields for country and state are dropdowns.

Comment: -1 -> You should add what you've tried, what you encountered, issues, etc etc. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Though bonus karma for you for drawing out your intent (though HTML/CSS could've sufficed in something like Codepen).

Comment: @rkeet actually I hadn't done the same as I have mentioned here. I had written the code in a similar way which cannot be disclosed. So I thought of asking this way. I understand I should have added my code snippet instead of the image. But I hadn't done it so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using the first submit for populate the state dropdown. You don't have to do like this. You can use AJAX and onchange of country you can populate the states.

Comment: -1 -> If you're going to answer a question about "how" something can done on a question without code, you should at minimum provide an example. A one-line opinion is not an answer. And you mean JavaScript using Ajax, Ajax is not a language. See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)